# Less-repetitive code for document-analyzer

Tags: object-oriented, ruby

I've refactored my code such that every function has only one responsibility. Now I'd like like to work on making it DRY.

I'm noticing a lot of duplication in the `DocumentAnalyzer` class. In nearly every function, I make a reference to `@document`.

Should my one-statement functions be collapsed into one line?

```
require 'set'

class Document
    attr_reader :words
    def initialize(words)
        @words = words
    end
end


class DocumentAnalyzer
    def initialize(document)
      @document = document
    end

    def unique_words
        @document.words.to_set
    end

    def unique_words_count
        unique_words.count
    end

  def word_count
    @document.words.size
  end

  def total_characters
    total = 0.0
    @document.words.each { |word| total += word.size }
    total   
  end

  def average_word_length
    total_characters / word_count
  end
end

d = Document.new %w(here are some words)
da = DocumentAnalyzer.new(d)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my eyes, there should really only be one class: `Document`.

As you noticed, the methods in `DocumentAnalyzer` all use `@document`. The analyzer class is so tied up in `Document` (and its methods are so simple) that it probably shouldn't be a wholly separate class.

But if there's a reason for it to be separate class (I can't think of any), then there's nothing inherently wrong in referencing the same variable in several places.

DRY does not mean "Don't ever repeat anything, ever!". It means "Don't duplicate *logic*". Accessing a variable isn't in itself logic; logic is what you do with it.

So if you want to always upcase all the words (or something), you should make a method to do *that* for you, instead of repeating that bit of logic everywhere you need it. But even so, you'd still have to call your `upcased_words` method in all those places, so it's not like you can avoid any and all repetition.

And no, don't collapse your methods. A single line is still a method body. Collapsing code is practically only used when you make a completely empty method or class on purpose, and want to really highlight that it's *intended* to be empty. E.g. `def no_op; end`.
You'll also see it in code that defines custom exception classes. The classes just inherit from an existing exception class, but they neither add or override anything; the point is just to define them as distinct classes. Hence, they're usually defined with `class CustomError < ExistingError; end`

Other things I noticed:

- Fix your indentation. Sometimes it's 2 spaces, sometimes it's 4. Stick to 2.
- Your `Document` class could - in its current form - be replaced by a plain array, really. It doesn't really do anything as it is right now. I'd expect a class named `Document` to (for instance) have methods to load/read a file or something. Instead, you give it an array, and it stores that array. But if you already have that array, why bother?
- You don't need `Set`. You can just do `words.uniq`
- Your `total_characters` method is odd. Why does `total` start out as a float? It'll always be an integer (unless you've discovered fractional characters)
- Speaking of, the summing up can be done with `inject` (aka `reduce`)

  ```
  def total_characters
    @document.words.inject(0) { |sum, word| sum += word.length }
  end
  ```
- Also, the method should probably be called `character_count` to stick to the convention established by `word_count` and `unique_word_count`. Neither of those is called `total_...`
- You should probably memoize your methods. That is, store the return value after calculating it the first time, so it doesn't have to be calculated again later:

  ```
  def total_characters
    @total_characters ||= @document.words.inject(0) { |sum, word| sum += word.length }
  end
  ```

  This code will return the instance variable immediately unless it's `nil` or `false`. Otherwise, it'll actually evaluate the right-hand expression (i.e. sum up the character count), assign the result to the instance variable, and *then* return the value.
- If you want to memoize return values, you should also `freeze` the `words` array. Otherwise you can do something like `some_document.words.fill("foobar")` after which your previously computed values stop making sense.
- I might just skip the `*_count` methods, since they're not even shortcuts. Anyone can call `some_document.words.count` or `some_document.unique_words.count`. Heck, you could even skip `unique_words` since it's the same as `words.uniq` (which is even shorter!).
  Basically, if the class itself doesn't rely on a method, and the logic is trivial, there's no reason to add that method (i.e. `unique_words` isn't used by the class, and is very trivial).
  *Edit* As jwg points out in the comments, memoization might be a good reason to add a method "ahead of time". Still, if the class itself doesn't have an obvious use for the method, think twice before adding it.

Here's what I might write

```
class Document
  attr_reader :words

  def initialize(words)
    @words = words.dup.freeze
  end

  def characters
    @characters ||= words.flat_map { |word| word.chars.to_a }.freeze
  end

  def average_word_length
    return 0 if words.empty? # avoid division by zero
    characters.count / words.count.to_f
  end
end
```

Again, I don't think the `*_count` methods add anything, since you can just write `.count` anyway:

```
doc = Document.new(%w(here are some words))
doc.words               # => ["here", "are", "some", "words"]
doc.characters          # => ["h", "e", "r", "e", "a", "r", "e", "s", "o", "m", "e", "w", "o", "r", "d", "s"]
doc.average_word_length # => 4.0
doc.words.count         # => 4
doc.characters.count    # => 16
doc.words.uniq          # => ["here", "are", "some", "words"]
doc.words.uniq.count    # => 4
```

As you can see, I've also left out the `unique_words` method, because it's so simple. *However,* if the `words` array is very long, it might be more efficient to provide a memoized method for people to use. I.e.

```
def unique_words
  @unique_words ||= words.uniq
end
```

Comment: Don't you think the possibilty of memoizing later (when it can be judged whether the optimization is worthwhile) makes it worth writing the method rather than the direct call now?

Comment: @jwg Indeed, that'd be a good reason to add the methods right away. But the `*_count` methods are so simple that memoization won't make much of a difference, so it's mostly `unique_words` that would benefit. I kept it apart for simplicity's sake, but your point is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the review, @Flambino!

The reason I created a `DocumentAnalyzer` class is because `Document`s don't actually have unique words, and don't inherently provide word counts and average word lengths. In real life, I would be asking the `DocumentAnalyzer` those questions.

Thanks for shedding light on the fact that DRY doesn't mean to not repeat myself ever, but not to repeat logic.

I'm a little lost on _memoization_ and `||=`. 

This is my first time seeing and using `#uniq` and `#freeze`. Cool stuff.

You've also helped me to become more mindful of how I name functions.

Comment: @DylanRichards Makes sense, but in real life, documents aren't just an array of words either. So if we're going to represent our "document" like that, we might as well give it all the other things too. As for `@x ||= y` you can read it as "if @x is non-nil/non-false, then set it to y. Otherwise, leave it alone". So the first time you call it, `@x` is nil, and thus it gets set to whatever's on the right-hand side. But the next time, `@x` already has a value, so it doesn't have to be set again.